# Android: WebView unable to show '%' percentage sign

Tags: android, webview

I try to play an html and js code in webview.
the code contains the sign '%' and the webview return an error ERROR_BAD_URL.

```
<style type='text/css'>
test{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

any idea?

-Z

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use `webview.loadDataWithBaseUrl` if `.loadData` causes problems.

Comment: Yes this works, you dont have to worry about special chars if you use this method.

Comment: webview.loadDataWithBaseUrl  -> webview.loadDataWithBaseURL

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this myself this weekend. Use "%25" to make the % symbol. Your new code should look like ...

```
<style type='text/css'>
    test{
        width: 100%25;
        height: 100%25;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I have done that but the problem is that now the page does not render as it should be.

Comment: % isn't the only character that needs to be escaped, see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4401

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html,"text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```